# Strange compiler behaviour in multi module project

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

I have the following project structure (on Windows 10 x64):

```
root-folder: containing parent pom, defining 1.8 for build and group/version, listing sub1, sub2, sub3 as modules
sub1: first module (jar), refering to parent pom
sub2: second module (jar), refering to parent pom, sub1 as dependency
sub3: third module (jar), refering to parent pom, sub2 as dependency
```

Now, when I do a `mvn clean install` separately in each module in the order of declaration above, everything builds fine.

But, when I do a `mvn clean install` on the parent pom, sub1 and sub2 build fine and in sub3 I get the ominous build error

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_181). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page [..]
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$1 from class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLiteral
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLiteral.getValue(JCTree.java:2044)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.merge(JavacParser.java:1034)
[..]
```

I updated to latest JDK 8 and Maven, but still the same error. I confirmed that JAVA_HOME and PATH are set correctly (since I do have newer JDKs on the system). Also I increased Memory for Maven through MAVEN_OPTS, but also no change.

Has anyone ever had a similar behaviour and could show me a solution or at least present an idea what could cause that? What is different when compiling each one manually or let maven do it? Could the dependencies be a problem or is it more likely something in my own code?

Comment: Can you compile it with an earlier JDK e.g. 1.8.0_151?

Comment: No, I had exactly that version before trying to update JDK, the error was the same.

Comment: Looks like a bug, can you post the code that causes it? You can try building with Java 9, there was a possibly similar bug in javac [JDK-8028415 : TreeMaker.Literal(Object) creates invalid JCLiterals when passed a Character](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8028415).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform one additional test to confirm the problem. Run `mvn clean install -pl :sub3 -am` from the root directory. If the builds fails with the same compiler error than you confirmed that it behaves differently from the root directory and from the `sub3` module.

As per https://github.com/ztellman/virgil/issues/16 and few similar issues this could be caused by dependencies e.g. Lombok generating bytecode in unsupported version.

Compare the resolved Maven dependencies by running `mvn dependency:tree` in two different ways:

1. From the project root directory, look at the dependency tree for the `sub3` module that fails compilation.
2. In the `sub3` module directly.

If they are not the same identify the library or the dependency version that's different.

If that won't work isolate the compiler task executing in each Maven module. This can be done by setting [Maven Compiler Plugin compile:compile properties](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html):

```
 maven.compiler.compilerReuseStrategy=alwaysNew
 maven.compiler.fork=true
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I confirmed that building it from root with discrete module list as you said first, results in the same compile error. Regarding the dependency tree, it is the same for both methods. So what does that mean now?

Comment: @AlexanderRühl can you test with `maven.compiler.compilerReuseStrategy=alwaysNew` and `maven.compiler.fork=true` property set? Try any other option that isolates the `javac` compiler.

Comment: Ok, I think I could identify the problem, I stumbled over it, when trying your suggestion with JDK 9, which then showed, that a plugin which I have in sub2 and which analyzes bytecode was the problem. Still, I don't understand in which way this affects sub3 while building sub2 was ok, any idea?

Comment: @AlexanderRühl most likely it pollutes the JVM that runs Maven so every module after `sub2` will fail. Try preventing compiler reuse and forking with the options I have suggested, that way each module will get a fresh compiler at the expense of build time.

Comment: Your suggestion with the compiler isolation properties works, so even with the plugin it works now from the parent. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @AlexanderRühl which Maven plugin was the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/sdaschner/jaxrs-analyzer-maven-plugin
I will file an issue there.